# I am trying to connect to a database that I created with java using hibernate. I am getting this error and I am not sure why

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a database that I created with java in eclipse using hibernate. It is supposed to connect to the payroll database and insert records into the student table but I am getting this error! I inserted the jdbc connect and the other required jar files. I am not sure why it's not working. Please help.

**Error:**

```
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:10 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.3.Final
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/payroll]
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 3 (min=1)
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    Jul 14, 2022 2:34:11 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
    INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@304b9f1a] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
    Hibernate: 
        select
            student0_.id as id1_0_,
            student0_.email as email2_0_,
            student0_.first_name as first_na3_0_,
            student0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_ 
        from
            student student0_
    Hibernate: 
        select
            student0_.id as id1_0_0_,
            student0_.email as email2_0_0_,
            student0_.first_name as first_na3_0_0_,
            student0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_0_ 
        from
            student student0_ 
        where
            student0_.id=?
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@5eb97ced is closed
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142)
        at models.Student.get(Student.java:131)
        at Driver.main(Driver.java:24)
```

Driver Class(driver.java)

```java
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import org.hibernate.*;
    import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
    import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
    import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
    
    import models.Student;
    
    public class Driver {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Student stu =new Student();//1,"Simone","Charles","@Home");
            //stu.create();
            List<Student> students=stu.readAll();
            for(Student s: students) {
                System.out.println(s.getFirstName());           
            }
            Student s1=stu.get(4);
            System.out.println(s1.getFirstName());
            //sstu.delete(2);
            //getCurrentSessionFromConfig();
            
    
        }
        
    
    public static Session getCurrentSessionFromConfig() {
      // SessionFactory in Hibernate 5 example
      Configuration config = new Configuration();
      config.configure();
      // local SessionFactory bean created
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      return session;
    }
    
    
    public static Session getCurrentSessionX() {
      // Hibernate 5.4 SessionFactory example without XML
      Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
      settings.put("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      settings.put("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
      settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", 
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate_examples");
      settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
      settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
      settings.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
      settings.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
      settings.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    
      ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                        .applySettings(settings).build();
    
      MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
      // metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(Player.class);
      Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();
    
      // here we build the SessionFactory (Hibernate 5.4)
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      return session;
    }
    }
```

Hibernate xml file

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Version 8 MySQL hiberante-cfg.xml example for Hibernate 5 -->
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <!-- property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/payroll</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>
        <!--property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property-->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- mapping class="com.mcnz.jpa.examples.Player" / -->
        <mapping class="models.Student" />
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

SessionBuilder File

```java
    package factories;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    
    import models.Student;
    
    public class SessionFactoryBuilder {
        
         private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    
            
         public  static SessionFactory getSessionFactory () {
             if(sessionFactory==null) {
                 try {
                     Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
                       // session =sessionFactory.openSession();
                        
                /* sessionFactory =new
                         Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass
                         (Student.class).buildSessionFactory();
                         */
                 }catch(RuntimeException e) {System.out.println(e.toString());}
             }
             return sessionFactory;
         }
        public static void closeSessionFactory () {
             if(sessionFactory!=null) {
                 sessionFactory.close();
             }
        }
    
    }
```

Student Class

```java
   
    package models;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    
    import factories.SessionFactoryBuilder;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name="student")
    public class Student {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        int id;
        
        @Column(name="first_name")
        String firstName;
        
        @Column(name="last_name")
        String lastName;
        
        @Column(name="email")
        String email;
        
        
        public Student() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.email = email;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        
        public void create() {
            Session session =SessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction transaction= session.beginTransaction();
            //Student stu=(Student) session.get(Student.class, this.id);
            //stu.setFirstName(firstName);
            //stu.setLastName(lastName);
            session.save(this);
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
        }
        public List<Student> readAll(){
            List<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<>();
            Session session =SessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction transaction= session.beginTransaction();
            studentList=(List<Student>) session.createQuery("From Student").getResultList();
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
            return studentList;
        }
    public void delete(int id) {
            Session session =SessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory()
                 .getCurrentSession();
            Transaction transaction= session.beginTransaction();
            //Student stu=(Student) session.get(Student.class, this.id);        
            //session.delete(stu);
            
             // Delete a persistent object
            Student student = session.get(Student.class, id);
            if (student != null) {
                session.delete(student);
                System.out.println("student  deleted");
            }
    
            // Delete a transient object
      /*      Student student2 = new Student();
            student2.setId(2);
            session.delete(student2);
            System.out.println("Student 2 is deleted");
        */    
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
    }
    public void update() {
        Session session =SessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory()
             .getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction= session.beginTransaction();
        //Student stu=(Student) session.get(Student.class, this.id);        
        session.update(this);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
    public Student get(int id) {
        Student stu=null;
        Transaction transaction=null;
        try(Session session =SessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory()
             .getCurrentSession()){
            transaction= session.beginTransaction();
        
        
            stu=(Student) session.get(Student.class, id);       
            session.delete(stu);
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            if(transaction!=null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return stu;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'd appreciate separated snippets

Comment: In which line are you opening a connection?

Comment: @nickkladis in line 65 of driver.java

Comment: @sm3sher I tried my best to edit the original post to make it more easy to read and understand. I separated the snippets also. There are 4 files in total.